# what is the reason of PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_REPCAT_INTERNAL_PACKAGE' must be declared

Tags: oracle

In the user_errors I have this error

> > PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_REPCAT_INTERNAL_PACKAGE' must be declared

what is the cause of this error and how to solve it ?. I searched over the internet and nothing is clear.

Comment: Some code is referencing this package and it seems the user under which the code runs does not have access to this package. The name of the package suggests it is an Oracle system  package only to be used internally.

Comment: you are sugesting that he doest not have priveliges for it ? how can I be sure ?

Comment: grant execute on sys.DBMS_REPCAT_INTERNAL_PACKAGE to <some_user>

Comment: even if he doesnt have access priveleges. he will get identifier must be declared ?